# Looping thought dictionary elements and combining (also adding) on similar keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I would have more than "key1" and "key2", I could have 20 or more.

```py
my_dict = {"key1": [{"A": 0}, {"B": 1}, {"C": 0}, {"D": 0},
                    {"A": 0}, {"B": 0}, {"C": 0}, {"D": 0},
                    {"A": 0}, {"B": 1}, {"C": 0}, {"D": 0}],
           "key2": [{"A": 0}, {"B": 0}, {"C": 0}, {"D": 0},
                    {"A": 1}, {"B": 0}, {"C": 0}, {"D": 0}, 
                    {"A": 0}, {"B": 0}, {"C": 0}, {"D": 0},
                    {"A": 1}, {"B": 0}, {"C": 0}, {"D": 0},
                    {"A": 0}, {"B": 0}, {"C": 0}, {"D": 0}],
            "key+:"..etc..}
```

My final output would look:

```
new_dict = {"key1": [{"A": 0}, {"B": 2}, {"C": 0}, {"D": 0}],
            "key2": [{"A": 2}, {"B": 0}, {"C": 0}, {"D": 0}]}
```

I tried:

```
new_dict = defaultdict(int)
f_dict = {}
for org in my_dict.keys():
    f_dict[str(org)] = []
    for key, dict_list in my_dict.items():
        for d in dict_list:
            for k, v in d.items():
                new_dict[k] += v
    f_dict[str(org)].append(dict(new_dict))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use @Cat's solution if you want

```
f: Dict[str, List[Dict[str, int]]] -> Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]
```

Use mine if you want

```
f: Dict[str, List[Dict[str, int]]] -> Dict[str, List[Dict[str, int]]]
```

### Solution

Might be overkill, but I wanted to mess around with some functions I rarely use. To be honest, I'm not totally sure I annotated the types correctly.

```py
import itertools, functools
from typing import Iterator, Iterable, List


def tuple_sum(t1: tuple, t2: tuple) -> tuple:
    """Assumes both `t1` and `t2` are 2-tuples and that they match in the first element."""
    (key, x), (_, y) = t1, t2
    return (key, x + y)


def tuple_union(tuple_group: itertools.groupby) -> tuple:
    """Unions a group of tuples with matching 'keys', with `tuple_sum` as aggregator."""
    return functools.reduce(tuple_sum, tuple_group)


def group_tuples(tuples: Iterable[tuple]) -> itertools.groupby:
    """Yields tuples grouped by key. Assumes `tuples` are already sorted by key."""
    yield from (g for _, g in itertools.groupby(tuples, key=lambda t: t[0]))


def package_tuples(tuple_iterator: Iterator[tuple]) -> List[dict]:
    """Packages each tuple in `tuple_iterator` as a standalone `dict`"""
    return [dict((t,)) for t in tuple_iterator]


def consolidate(d_list: List[dict]) -> List[dict]:
    """Groups dictionaries with matching keys, then sums their values."""
    tuples = []
    for d in d_list:
        tuples.extend(d.items())
    sorted_tuples = sorted(tuples, key=lambda t: t[0])
    groups = group_tuples(sorted_tuples)
    return package_tuples(tuple_union(g) for g in groups)
```

### Usage

```py
>>> {key: consolidate(d_list) for key, d_list in my_dict.items()}
{'key1': [{'A': 0}, {'B': 2}, {'C': 0}, {'D': 0}],
 'key2': [{'A': 2}, {'B': 0}, {'C': 0}, {'D': 0}]}
```

### Explanation

1. The `tuple_sum()` function is hopefully pretty clear, it takes two 2-tuples and sums their second element. It assumes the two tuples passed have matching "keys" where the "key" is considered the first element.
2. The `tuple_union()` function takes a group of tuples whose keys match, e.g., `[("a", 1), ("a", 5), ("a", 3)]` and sums them using `tuple_sum()`, returning a single tuple e.g., `("a", 9)`.
3. The `group_tuples()` function takes a *sorted* iterable of tuples and returns a generator which yields the groups. An iterable of tuples is considered "sorted" when all tuples with matching keys are adjacent, e.g.: `[("a", 1), ("a", 5), ("b", 3), ("b", 7), ("b" 3), ("c", 1)]`. The `itertools.groupby()` function returns an iterator which yields those groups, e.g. `("a", 1), ("a", 5)`, and then `("b", 3), ("b", 7), ("b" 3)`.
4. The `package_tuples()` function takes an iterator which yields tuples and packages each tuple into a dictionary, e.g., `dict((("a", 9),)) -> {"a": 9}`.

The way the `consolidate()` function works is by taking a list of dictionaries and "melting" them all together as one big list of tuples. Then it sorts those tuples, then passes those sorted tuples to the `group_tuples` generator.

### Alternative output structure

If you want this as output instead:

```py
{'key1': {'A': 0, 'B': 2, 'C': 0, 'D': 0},
 'key2': {'A': 2, 'B': 0, 'C': 0, 'D': 0}}
```

You can modify the `consolidate()` function as follows:

```py
def consolidate(d_list: List[dict]) -> List[dict]:
    """Groups dictionaries with matching keys, then sums their values."""
    tuples = []
    for d in d_list:
        tuples.extend(d.items())
    sorted_tuples = sorted(tuples, key=lambda t: t[0])
    return dict(tuple_union(g) for g in group_tuples(sorted_tuples))
```

This also means you can get rid of the `package_tuples()` function altogether. At this point though, @Cat's solution is much more concise as this type of consolidation is much simpler.

Comment: Glad I could help. The built-in itertools and functools modules are pretty fun.

Comment: Using your above, is it also possible to return: new_dict = {'key1': {'A': 0, 'B': 2, 'C':..} 'key2': {...}}

Comment: @user1040259 yep! See my edit.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @user1040259 if the `dict` of `dict` structure is what you *actually* need, then @Cat's solution is probably better. I haven't tested speed or memory, but at the very least theirs is simpler if `Dict[str, List[Dict[str, int]]] -> Dict[str, Dict[str, int]]` is your end goal. Mine is really only necessary if you want to preserve the input's structure.

Answer (score 2):

There are several levels to this:

Outer level: dictionary with two unique keys
Each of those dictionaries holds a list (which I called `dict_list`) of smaller dictionaries

```
from collections import defaultdict

# initialize a new default dictionary
# this allows you to initialize each new key with a value of zero
new_dict = defaultdict(int)

for key, dict_list in my_dict.items():
    for d in dict_list:
        for k, v in d.items():
            new_dict[k] += v
```

**Edit 1:**
I didn't understand the question. It looks like you want to preserve the outer dictionary's keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_dict = {}
for key, dict_list in my_dict.items():
    new_dict[key] = defaultdict(int)
    for d in dict_list:
        for k, v in d.items():
            new_dict[key][k] += v
```

This would output new_dict in the format:
`new_dict = {'key1': {'A': 0, 'B': 2...} 'key2': {...}}`

If you want key1 and key2 to contain a list of dicts, after the previous code, you can add:

```
for key, d in new_dict.items():
    l = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        l.append({k: v})
    new_dict[key] = l
```

This would output new_dict in the format:
`new_dict = {'key1': [{'A': 0}, {'B': 2},...], 'key2': [{...}, ...]}`

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, my problem is how would I separate them, I updated my question.

Comment: Ah I see -- I didn't understand the question. Edited my answer.